# Ever-increasing RAM usage with low series cardinality

Tags: influxdb

I'm just testing influxdb 1.3.5 for storing a small number (~30-300) of very long integer series (worst case: `(86400)*(12*365) [sec/day * ((days/year)*12) * 1 device] = 378.432.000`)

e.g. the number of total points would be for 320 devices: `(86400)*(12*365)*320 [sec/day * ((days/year)*12) * 320 devices] = 121.098.240.000`)

The series cardinality is low, it equals the number of devices. I'm using second-precision timestamps (that mode is enabled when I commit to influxdb via the php-API.
Yes, I really need to keep all the samples, so downsampling is not an option.

I'm inserting the samples as point-arrays of size 86400 per request sorted from oldest to newest. The behaviour is similar (OOM in both cases) for `inmem` and `tsi1` indexing modes.

Despite all that, **I'm not able to insert this number of points to the database without crashing it due to out of memory**. The host-vm has 8GiB of RAM and 4GiB of Swap which fill up completely. I cannot find anything about that setup being problematic in the documentation. I cannot find a notice that indicates this setup should result in a high RAM usage at all...

Does anyone have a hint on what could be wrong here?

Thanks and all the best!
b-

[ I asked the same question here but received no replies, that's the reason for crossposting: https://community.influxdata.com/t/ever-increasing-ram-usage-with-low-series-cardinality/2555 ]

Comment: I'd suggest trying other time series databases with lower RAM requirements comparing to InfluxDB. See [this benchmark results](https://medium.com/@valyala/insert-benchmarks-with-inch-influxdb-vs-victoriametrics-e31a41ae2893) as a reference.

Answer (score 0):

<s>I found out what the issue most likely was:</s>

I had a bug in my feeder that caused timestamps not being updated to lots of points with distinct values were written over and over again to the same timestamp/tag combination.

If you experience something similar, try double-checking each step in the pipeline for a time concerning error.

This was not the issue unfortunately, the ram usage rises nevertheless then importing more points than before.